# Exception has occurred. _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I copied the code from the browser when I tried it an error occurred, how do I solve it because I want to use this code as a reference in learning but the following error occurs

Exception has occurred.

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 1584 post 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
               items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                 return item. value == value;
               }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Dropdown 1.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)
```

```
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: DynamicDropdown(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class DynamicDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _DynamicDropdownState createState() => _DynamicDropdownState();
    }
    
    class _DynamicDropdownState extends State<DynamicDropdown> {
      String dropdownValue1 = 'Dropdown 1';
      String dropdownValue2 = 'Dropdown 2';
      List<String> dropdownItems1 = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
      List<String> dropdownItems2 = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Dynamic Dropdown'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                DropdownButtonFormField(
                  value: dropdownValue1,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue1 = newValue!;
                      if (dropdownValue1 == 'Item 1') {
                        dropdownItems2 = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];
                      } else if (dropdownValue1 == 'Item 2') {
                        dropdownItems2 = ['Item D', 'Item E', 'Item F'];
                      } else {
                        dropdownItems2 = ['Item G', 'Item H', 'Item I'];
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  items: dropdownItems1.map((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: dropdownValue2,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue2 = newValue!;
                    });
                  },
                  items: dropdownItems2.map((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 'dropdownValue1' should be from 'dropdownItems1' list. error comes from here - 'value: dropdownValue1' ,where you have assigned item from outside the list, check below code, I have edited your code;

```
  // String dropdownValue1 = 'Dropdown 1';
//  String dropdownValue2 = 'Dropdown 2';
  List<String> dropdownItems1 = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
  List<String> dropdownItems2 = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];
  String dropdownValue1;
  String dropdownValue2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    dropdownValue1 = dropdownItems1[0];
    dropdownValue2 = dropdownItems2[0];
  }
```